# std::source_location as non type template parameter

Tags: c++, c++20, std-source-location

In my infinite quest to push limits of what can be used as non type template parameter I was trying to see if I can use `std::source_location` as non type template parameter.
That failed with a weird message, since I presume source_location is some magical struct...

> type 'std::experimental::source_location' of non-type template
> parameter is not a structural type

It failed, so I tried to workaround that with using .file_name, but that also fails ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/474fcd)).

> note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: pointer to
> subobject of string literal is not allowed in a template argument

```
#include<iostream>
#include<experimental/source_location>

template<auto src_loc = std::experimental::source_location::current().file_name()>
void log_first(){
    static bool dummy =([]{
        std::cout << "Logging first call" + src_loc << std::endl;
    }(), false);
}

int main() {
    log_first();
    log_first();
}
```

Is there any way to make this work without use of macros?

To be clear I am asking about using `source_location` as template parameter, not about solving my toy example, it is just here to demonstrate potential use case.

Comment: This is invalid argument of template. Note that `const char*` can't be template arguement and this is result of [std::source_location::file_name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/file_name). Removing `auto` makes this clear https://godbolt.org/z/GnMa8d

Comment: @MarekR `char const*` _can_ be a template argument, even in C++03 https://godbolt.org/z/MEhPso. It's just that a template parameter cannot point to string literal and the origin of `file_name()` could be a string literal.

Comment: re. using `source_location::current()` in a default NTTP, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64300746/source-locationcurrent-evaluated-as-default-non-type-template-argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::source_location`](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.srcloc.class.general#lib:source_location) is specified as:

```cpp
  struct source_location {
    // ...

  private:
    uint_least32_t line_;               // exposition only
    uint_least32_t column_;             // exposition only
    const char* file_name_;             // exposition only
    const char* function_name_;         // exposition only
  };
```

And the rules for the kinds of types that can be used as non-template template parameters require that a type be *structural*, which means, from [[temp.param]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#7), emphasis mine:

> A *structural type* is one of the following:
>
> - a scalar type, or
> - an lvalue reference type, or
> - a literal class type with the following properties:
>
>   - **all base classes and non-static data members are public** and non-mutable and
>   - the types of all bases classes and non-static data members are structural types or (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof.

`source_location` does not have all of its non-static data members public, so it is not structural, so it is not usable as a non-type template parameter.

---

This part:

```cpp
template <auto src_loc = std::experimental::source_location::current().file_name()>
```

does not work because of [[temp.arg.nontype]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#3):

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, or for each non-static data member of reference or pointer type in a non-type template-parameter of class type or subobject thereof, the reference or pointer value shall not refer to or be the address of (respectively):
>
> - [...],
> - a string literal object ([lex.string]),
> - ...

---

But what you can do is create your own type, that is structural, that is constructible from `source_location`. It's just that the strings can't be `char const*`, they have to own the data. If you look in the examples in [P0732](https://wg21.link/p0732), we can build up:

```cpp
template <typename Char, size_t N>
struct basic_fixed_string { ... };

template <basic_fixed_string S> struct A {};

using T = A<"hello">;
```

That might be awkward to deal with in this case, so you could also just pick some reasonable max size and go with that.

Comment: do you know why constexpr const char* file_name() const noexcept; is also not allowed? 

Maybe because parent object is not constexpr friendly or member I get pointer to  is not consexpr friendly or...

Comment: OP is trying to use `.file_name()` as the object, not a `source_location` directly, so the part you emphasized in the quote is not really the right one.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Right, well the quote applies to both, it's just the emphasized part.

Comment: Barry I did not really got your last part of the answer, did you mean something like this?
https://godbolt.org/z/6od6EP 
Problem with this is that it seems that source_location::current is broken for this usecase, since I get location of template function, not callers(I presume because "calling" of current is done at compile time). Do you know if this is by design or just a unfortunate limitation?